# How can I run Nexus IQ analysis on Gitlab CI and send results to existing Nexus IQ server?

Tags: gitlab

We have been using Bamboo for CI for our Maven  Java project, but now moving to Gitlab CI, and we would like to automatically send results to our Nexus IQ server, the way we did with Bamboo

With Bamboo it was easy, you just added the IQ Evaluation task.

But how do you do it with Gitlab CI?

Comment: I assume you have added the clm-maven-plugin to your pom?

Comment: Nexus IQ is a licensed application, suggest filing a support request or checking with your CSE at Sonatype.